# Pandas Profiling

Tags: pandas, import, report, profiling

I have been struggling with the installation of pandas profiling.

from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

ImportError: cannot import name 'ABCIndexClass' from 'pandas.core.dtypes.generic' (C:\Users\Harpreet Singh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\generic.py)

Can any one please help & sort this for me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.